# After reset the Gridview .the grid view record will shown in export excel sheet

Tags: c#, gridview

I have 3 buttons: View button, Reset button and Export excel button with in a date range(start date and end date).
In View button, the gridview will shown within a date range.
In Reset button, the gridview will reset.

I used,

```
gvrecord.datasource=null;
gvrecord.databind();
```

But after reset, the gridview record will shown in export excel sheet.

Comment: Where are you pulling the data from - by writing `gvrecord.datasource = null` you don't clear the data from that data source, you are simply disconnecting it from the gridView.

Answer (score 0):

To reset GridView data, use:

```
gvrecord.Rows.Clear();
```